# Change a menu item's background image when that page has been clicked

Tags: css, menu

(There are many similar questions, but I wanted to do it with CSS)

I have the menu default css as #menu li a {background-image: url('../images/button.gif');}

Then my thinking was to put some inline css on each page, using matching nth child.  The Home page is (1), next page (2) etc., so in the Home page I try to change the bg image with:

```
<style>
    #menu li a:nth-child(1)  {
       background-image: url("../images/button-on.gif") !important;
    }
</style>
```

It nearly works - the css is correct when I inspect that link, the default img is removed, but the replacement img doesn't load.

So, is there some sort of pre-load of the file required, because this css is in-line?

Comment: When you use path inside css, it is relative to the css file's container folder. Can you check if that path is correct ? `../images/button-on.gif`

Comment: if you have .css file in some directory and html file in root, then you should use `/images` in html and `../images` in css file

Answer (score 0):

Images loaded via inline CSS do not need a preload or something. If your CSS works but the images won't load, it most probably has to do with the misunderstanding of relative paths.

How to fix this: the browser tools for network analysis should show you the path were the browser tries to load your image while getting back a 404 error because the image is not found. You should inspect that path to find out what you where doing wrong with your relative img src.

Answer (score 0):

Quite right & thanks folks, this idiot had the path wrong as surmised; I had just copied the path used in the css file, which off course is in a different location.

At least I can now say this quite an efficient way to highlight the current page in a menu.